# Angular another view for tree

Tags: angularjs

I write directive for menu/tree view, but each level need to be on separate view: on load we see only links level 1, after click on link open links level 2 - but on screen we see only links level 2 - not parent. To go back  - there is breadcrumbs.
How I do this?

For example:

On first screen:
 Link1
 Link2
 LInk3

After click on Link1 on screen only children link1 and line navigation:

Link1>

Child 1 Link1

Child 2 Link1

Child 3 Link1

After click on Child 1 Link1 on screen only children Child 1 Link1 and line navigation:

Link1>Child 1 Link1

Child 1 Child 1 Link1

Child 2 Child 1 Link1

Child 3 Child 1 Link1

All lines - links or on chidren or if not - to page with image.
Image have only children without children.

Comment: Add some codes or a fiddle/plnkr please.

Comment: added explanation

Comment: Add codes please not an explanation.